# turn a dict that may contain a pandas dataframe to several dicts

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dict that may be 'infinitely' nested and contain several pandas `DataFrame`'s (all the `DataFrame`'s have the same amount of rows).

I want to create a new dict for each row in the `DataFrame`'s, with the row being transformed to a dict (the key's are the column names) and the rest of the dictionary staying the same.

Note: I am not making a cartesian product between the rows of the different `DataFrame`'s.

what would be the best and most pythonic way to do it?

Example:

the original `dict`:

```
d = {'a': 1,
    'inner': {
        'b': 'string',
        'c': pd.DataFrame({'c_col1': range(1,3), 'c_col2': range(2,4)})
        },
     'd': pd.DataFrame({'d_col1': range(4,6), 'd_col2': range(7,9)})
    }
```

the desired result:

```
lst_of_dicts = [
   {'a': 1,
    'inner': {
        'b': 'string',
        'c': {
                'c_col1': 1, 'c_col2':2
             }
        },
     'd': {
             'd_col1': 4, 'd_col2': 7
          }
    },

    {'a': 1,
    'inner': {
        'b': 'string',
        'c': {
                'c_col1': 2, 'c_col2': 3
             }
        },
     'd': {
             'd_col1': 5, 'd_col2': 8
          }
    }
]
```

Comment: there are many rows in the dataframe (for eg. c), but its missing in your desired result. Have you tried Pandas.DataFrame.to_dict() ?

Comment: yes `to_dict` will be part of the solution. I think you misunderstood the question though,  the desired result is to 'split' to rows to different dictionaries. as you can see the second dictionary contains the second rows from the `DataFrame`'s `'d'` and `'c'`.

Comment: I answered this in a code review [post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/204453/turn-a-dict-that-may-contain-a-pandas-dataframe-to-several-dicts)